# In OLS is the vector of residuals always 0?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to show that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^ne_i = 0$$

I have two hints, so to speak:

$$ HX = X$$
where $H$ is the hat matrix, and that $$\sum_{i=1}^ne_i = e'1$$

My solution is as follows:

$$e'1 = Y'(I-H)1=[(X\beta)' - (X\beta)'H]1=(\beta'X' - \beta'X'X(X'X)^{-1}X')1 $$
$$=(\beta'X' - \beta'X')1 = 01 = 0 $$

Seems simple enough but this implies that $e'$ and by extension $e$ is always a vector of zeros, which seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Careful, you're using the existence of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ here...

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the residuals is zero , it does not necessarily mean that 
 $\mathbf e'$ is a vector of zeros.

Example:

$\mathbf e'\cdot \mathbf 1=\begin{pmatrix}-2&-3&5\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=-2-3+5=0$